# Localstack - Expose API-Gateway Rest Api

Tags: docker, api-gateway, localstack

how can I create a "custom domain name" in localstack (docker container) to proxy all incoming requests from http://localhost:12345/* to [http://localhost:4566/restapis/j1a28etb48/dev/*user_request*/*](http://localhost:4566/restapis/j1a28etb48/dev/_user_request_/) ?

is that possible?

Comment: Did you find a solution for this?

Comment: You can install apache server and do reverse proxy, you can even add a host name entry in the /etc/hosts to pretend yourdomain.com something like that